# How do I get bootstrap modal working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Below is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascipt" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal for file filter -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already looked up answers for the same question. Solutions for the same recommend loading jquery.js before bootstrap.js. Mine doesn't work inspite of taking care of the same.

**EDIT**
Am now using bootstrap-3.3.4 and jquery-2.1.3

Comment: Do you have any JS errors in the console?

Comment: which boostrap version are you using...?

Comment: @D4V1D, No errors in the console.

Comment: @Lalitpatadiya, 3.3.2

Comment: Your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/6y8jbg2t/

Comment: just change the bootstrap library .
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js

from here
your code should work

Comment: @Banik, I am now using bootstrap-3.3.4 and jquery-2.1.3. Still not working...

Comment: could u please change one thing ,remove type="text/javascipt" from bootstrap.min.js script.

Comment: @Banik, It worked. :-). I wonder how this was messing it up though. By the way, if you can put up the same as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: thnks I added it as answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
     type="text/javascipt"
```

from bootstrap.min.js script.